# Azure Notification Hub. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. NotificationId cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-notificationhub, azure-sdk-.net

I'm working with Azure .Net SDK. 
When I do `SendDirectNotificationAsync`, I receive `NotificationOutcome`. Then I get `NotificationId` from outcome and at once I do `GetNotificationOutcomeDetailsAsync`. I get  response with `404` error. But If I try to repeat one more time, I get  `NotificationDetail`.

Code:

```
var outcome = hub.SendDirectNotificationAsync(notification, messageCreated.Entity.PushToken).Result;
```

Unfortunately, I haven't option to use `await`.

Exception:

```
Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Messaging.MessagingEntityNotFoundException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. NotificationId 'dcd8c78360d24dfa9e99dadfc6b68593-20180403085427-2001954715-1' cannot be found.TrackingId:1f5a51d0-547a-428d-a845-7a164baebf74_G13,TimeStamp:4/3/2018 8:54:27 AM
  Module "Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Common.ExceptionDispatcher", line 7, col 0, in Throw
    Void Throw(System.Exception)
  Module "Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Common.AsyncResult", line 310, col 0, in End
    TAsyncResult End[TAsyncResult](System.IAsyncResult)
  Module "Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubManager+<>c", line 0, col 0, in GetNotificationAsync { <lambda> }
    Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationDetails <GetNotificationAsync>b__24_1(System.IAsyncResult)
  Module "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory 1", line 15, col 0, in FromAsyncCoreLogic
    Void FromAsyncCoreLogic(System.IAsyncResult, System.Func 2[System.IAsyncResult,TResult], System.Action 1[System.IAsyncResult], System.Threading.Tasks.Task 1[TResult], Boolean)
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
  Module "System.Net.HttpWebRequest", line 273, col 0, in EndGetResponse
    System.Net.WebResponse EndGetResponse(System.IAsyncResult)
  Module "Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationRequestAsyncResult 1+<>c", line 0, col 0, in GetAsyncSteps { <lambda> }
    Void <GetAsyncSteps>b__26_3(TAsyncResult, System.IAsyncResult)
  Module "Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1", line 44, col 0, in StepCallback
    Boolean StepCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
```

Can somebody provide any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the `GetNotificationOutcomeDetailsAsync` would leverage the REST API [Per Message Telemetry: Get Notification Message Telemetry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt608135.aspx). For the 404 response code, the official documentation has stated as follows:

> Telemetry does not exist. This may be because the notification ID is invalid or because the message has not progressed far enough in processing. If you receive a 404 code, wait and try again after 10s. This state can continue for up to 30 minutes.

**Note:** The above API is only available for [Standard tier notification hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/notification-hubs/). Moreover, you could follow [Diagnose dropped notifications in Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer) to narrow down this issue.