# Azure Notification Hub SDK not setting custom installation Id

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am using Azure Notification Hub SDK to set a new installation for a device. When I call the service I set the InstallationId property using a custom string.
Nevertheless when I get the Installation using that string I receive a 404 Not Found response.

```
var installation = new Installation()
        {
            InstallationId = deviceInstallation.InstallationId.Replace(" ", ""),
            PushChannel = deviceInstallation.PushChannel.Replace(" ", ""),
            PushChannelExpired = false,
            Tags = deviceInstallation.Tags,
            ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
        };

 if (deviceInstallation.ExpiryDate.HasValue)
        {
            installation.ExpirationTime = deviceInstallation.ExpiryDate.Value;
        }

        if (_installationPlatforms.TryGetValue(deviceInstallation.Platform, out var platform))
        {
            installation.Platform = platform;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }     
            await _hub.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation, token);
```

Then I retrieved the registration using the PNS Token to ckeck if the registration was made, and it was.

```
await _hub.GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync(channelToken, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Nevertheless when I get the Installation using that string I receive a 404 Not Found response.

Verify your Azure Notification Hub configuration, your connection string, and the hub name. I had implemented the below code as per your requirement please check.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    private static string connectionString = "YourNotificationHubConnectionString";
    private static string hubName = "YourNotificationHubName";

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var installationId = "YourInstallationId";
        var pushChannel = "YourPushChannel";
        var tags = new List<string> { "tag1", "tag2" };

        // Create an instance of NotificationHubClient
        var hubClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(connectionString, hubName);

        var installation = new Installation
        {
            InstallationId = installationId,
            PushChannel = pushChannel,
            PushChannelExpired = false,
            Tags = tags,
            ExpirationTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1)
        };

        try
        {
            await hubClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);
            Console.WriteLine("Installation created successfully.");

            // Retrieve registrations using PNS token (pushChannel)
            var registrations = await hubClient.GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync(pushChannel, 100);
            foreach (var registration in registrations)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Registration Id: {registration.RegistrationId}");
                // You can perform further operations with the registration here
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

- Adding error handling around the retrieval process to capture any exceptions or errors during the retrieval of the installation.
- I tried in a console app and installed [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](https://i.imgur.com/SWlRwXl.png) package. Iam able to build the code with no errors.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

For more details please refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632857/azure-notification-hub-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-404-not-found-no#:%7E:text=For%20the%20404%20response%20code%2C%20the%20official%20documentation,state%20can%20continue%20for%20up%20to%2030%20minutes.) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632857/azure-notification-hub-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-404-not-found-no#:%7E:text=For%20the%20404%20response%20code%2C%20the%20official%20documentation,state%20can%20continue%20for%20up%20to%2030%20minutes.)

Comment: this is correct but there is a difference between RegistrationId and InstallationId. I can retrieve the registrationId using PNS Handle, but I cannot retrieve the installation using the installationID i provided when creating the installation itself.

Comment: Please check that the format of the InstallationId you are providing matches the format that Azure Notification Hubs expects.

Comment: Where can i verify that?

Comment: Please check in the "Installations" section inside the portal, you can see a list of all the installations associated with your notification hub.

Comment: That's what I was looking for but there is no "installation" section on the portal.